# Setting Windows Flag on a QDialog hides the form

Tags: c++, qt

I currently have a form that inherits from QDialog.
Now in order to hide the `?` icon on the form I am doing something like this in the constructor.

```
foo::foo(QWidget *parent): QDialog(parent)
{
    .....
    this->setWindowFlags(Qt::WindowTitleHint);
}
```

The problem with this is that the Dialog does not show up. If I ommit the flags line it shows up. I am using QT 5.1.1

Comment: I don't see how WindowTitleHint is related to the "?" button. Do you want to hide the whole title? Try `windowFlags() & ~Qt::WindowContextHelpButtonHint` or `windowFlags() & ~Qt::WindowTitleHint`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eventually you want to call

```
this->setWindowFlags(this->windowFlags() | Qt::WindowTitleHint);
```

Comment: I tried replacing my statement with yours. The Dialog appears however the question mark is still there

Comment: Try setting custom dialog hint and your needed flags: ```setWindowFlags(Qt::CustomizeWindowHint | Qt::WindowTitleHint);```

Answer (score 2):

To answer the question, here the solution:

`setWindowFlags(windowFlags() & ~Qt::WindowContextHelpButtonHint);`

If you want the minimize and maximize options, do the following:

`setWindowFlags(windowFlags() & ~Qt::WindowContextHelpButtonHint) | Qt::WindowMaximizeButtonHint | Qt::WindowMinimizeButtonHint);`

Answer (score 0):

To get this to work on linux I had to use both options described above:

```
setFixedSize(width(), height());
setWindowFlags(Qt::Drawer);
```

The result is a dialog with only a close button.